# PhoneGap + JQueryMobile - Option field text size

Tags: android, jquery

I am developing a cross-platform application using phonegap and jquery. In my HTML document I have a select element with several options. On Android, when the user taps on the select element, an overview of all options opens using the standard Android dropdown (something like an overlay with all options). So far so nice, but unfortunately my options have too much text that eventually gets cut off at the end. How can I adjust the size of the text here? Any hints? Adjusting the text size via CSS is simply ignored. I am thinking of using radio buttons instead, but that is just a workaround for me.

Answer (score 0):

I read listview is another way to handle this problem. Select is fairly limited to my understanding.